# TBB concurrent_queue errors

Tags: intel, tbb

Can't seem to compile program with even a mention of concurrent_queue.

code contains this

```
#include <tbb/concurrent_queue.h>
```

And second I add anywhere in the code

```
concurrent_queue<int> tbbqueue;
```

This is the error I get on compile. I am able to compile some other tbb related code using tasks etc, but this for some reason is not working.

```
    g++ -O3 -Wall -pthread -std=c++11 -ltbb -o tbbqueue.o tbbqueue.cpp 
tbbqueue.cpp: In function ‘void* Agent(void*)’:
tbbqueue.cpp:46:10: warning: unused variable ‘elements’ [-Wunused-variable]
tbbqueue.cpp:47:9: warning: unused variable ‘elementsSize’ [-Wunused-variable]
/tmp/ccQg8OKZ.o: In function `tbb::strict_ppl::internal::concurrent_queue_base_v3<int>::~concurrent_queue_base_v3()':
tbbqueue.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10strict_ppl8internal24concurrent_queue_base_v3IiED2Ev[_ZN3tbb10strict_ppl8internal24concurrent_queue_base_v3IiED5Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::NFS_Free(void*)'
/tmp/ccQg8OKZ.o: In function `tbb::strict_ppl::concurrent_queue<int, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int> >::deallocate_block(void*, unsigned long)':
tbbqueue.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10strict_ppl16concurrent_queueIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEE16deallocate_blockEPvm[_ZN3tbb10strict_ppl16concurrent_queueIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEE16deallocate_blockEPvm]+0x4): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::NFS_Free(void*)'
/tmp/ccQg8OKZ.o: In function `tbb::strict_ppl::concurrent_queue<int, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int> >::allocate_block(unsigned long)':
tbbqueue.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10strict_ppl16concurrent_queueIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEE14allocate_blockEm[_ZN3tbb10strict_ppl16concurrent_queueIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEE14allocate_blockEm]+0xf): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::NFS_Allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long, void*)'
tbbqueue.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10strict_ppl16concurrent_queueIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEE14allocate_blockEm[_ZN3tbb10strict_ppl16concurrent_queueIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEE14allocate_blockEm]+0x2b): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id)'
/tmp/ccQg8OKZ.o: In function `tbb::strict_ppl::internal::concurrent_queue_base_v3<int>::~concurrent_queue_base_v3()':
tbbqueue.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10strict_ppl8internal24concurrent_queue_base_v3IiED0Ev[_ZN3tbb10strict_ppl8internal24concurrent_queue_base_v3IiED0Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::NFS_Free(void*)'
/tmp/ccQg8OKZ.o: In function `tbb::strict_ppl::concurrent_queue<int, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int> >::~concurrent_queue()':
tbbqueue.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10strict_ppl16concurrent_queueIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEED2Ev[_ZN3tbb10strict_ppl16concurrent_queueIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEED5Ev]+0x12d): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::NFS_Free(void*)'
/tmp/ccQg8OKZ.o: In function `tbb::strict_ppl::concurrent_queue<int, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int> >::~concurrent_queue()':
tbbqueue.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10strict_ppl16concurrent_queueIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEED0Ev[_ZN3tbb10strict_ppl16concurrent_queueIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEED0Ev]+0x12d): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::NFS_Free(void*)'
/tmp/ccQg8OKZ.o: In function `main':
tbbqueue.cpp:(.text.startup+0x32): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::NFS_Allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long, void*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tbbqueue.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What version of g++? Run "g++ -v" to find out.  The missing `tbb::internal::NFS_Allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long, void*)' suggests that libtbb.so is not being found, or the wrong one (32 vs. 64 bit) is being searched.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1):

The order, in which you specify libraries and source/object files for linking, matters.
See more details here: [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc)

In this case, the flag to link with TBB (`-ltbb`) was specified in the command line prior to the program source file (`tbbqueue.cpp`). So when the linker processed the TBB library it had seen no code that uses it, decided it is unnecessary, and removed all its symbols from consideration. Then, it saw external symbols in the object file compiled from `tbbqueue.cpp`, but not libraries where these symbols could be found.

If the order of options is changed like this:

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -pthread -std=c++11 -o tbbqueue.o tbbqueue.cpp -ltbb
```

the compilation should succeed.