# Cant compile C++ program with TBB Library

Tags: c++, linux, tbb

I have a C++ program and when I compile it with TBB Library, I am getting following errors.

ssca2.o: In function `~task':
/usr/include/tbb/task.h:533: undefined reference to`vtable for tbb::task'
/usr/include/tbb/task.h:533: undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
ssca2.o: In function`operator new':
/usr/include/tbb/task.h:961: undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const'
/usr/include/tbb/task.h:961: undefined reference to`tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const'
ssca2.o: In function `first_task::execute()':
/home/nandini/sto-stamp-master/stamp-0.9.10/ssca2/ssca2.cpp:101: undefined reference to`tbb::task::spawn_and_wait_for_all(tbb::task_list&)'
ssca2.o: In function `operator new':
/usr/include/tbb/task.h:935: undefined reference to`tbb::internal::allocate_root_proxy::allocate(unsigned long)'
ssca2.o:(.rodata._ZTI10first_task[_ZTI10first_task]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for tbb::task'
ssca2.o:(.rodata._ZTV10first_task[_ZTV10first_task]+0x28): undefined reference to`tbb::task::note_affinity(unsigned short)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ssca2] Error 1

Comment: Can you please explain more on how to remove these error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2642204/bartoszkp, http://stackoverflow.com/users/813002/genericjon, http://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115022/tbb-concurrent-queue-errors, it might be of help.